# Trigger to insert records into another table once any action in first table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table named `car`. How can I mount a *Trigger* in *PostgreSQL* where for each either *insert/update/delete* in that table follows *insertion* of such record/s into another table? The structure of those tables are almost same but second table `car2` would have no `PK` column as same record can be inserted there multiple times once *updated* in car and also have additional column with *timestamp* which would reflect the datetime when record/s has been inserted there.

```
Car
ID  [PK]
Name
Location

Car2
ID
Name
Location
InsertionDate
```

Comment: Is the second table meant for auditing history/changes on the first one? There's an example of that on [the wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger) and in [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-AUDIT-EXAMPLE).

Comment: If you want to insert on delete you probably want some kind of action field or a deleted flag in Car2

Comment: @clamp On delete deleted record/s should be inserted into car2

Comment: @Zegarek yes it's more like as audit table. Seems like ur 2nd link to be better for my purposes as it takes all data as well.

Comment: @Arie I think you meant the 1st one, the wiki example - than one takes a full before/after snapshot of the row, as well as the complete text of statement that affected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77653184/trigger-to-insert-records-into-another-table-once-any-action-in-first-table?noredirect=1#comment136899341_77653184), there's an [example in the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-AUDIT-EXAMPLE) - you can pretty much copy and paste it on your structure. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/FygWMo5s)

```
create table car(
id int generated by default as identity primary key,
name text,
location text);

create table car_audit(
operation char(1) NOT NULL,
stamp     timestamp NOT NULL,
userid    text      NOT NULL,
id int,
name text,
location text);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trf_process_car_audit() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $car_audit$
    BEGIN
        IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
            INSERT INTO car_audit SELECT 'D', now(), current_user, OLD.*;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
            INSERT INTO car_audit SELECT 'U', now(), current_user, NEW.*;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            INSERT INTO car_audit SELECT 'I', now(), current_user, NEW.*;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$car_audit$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_car_audit
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON car
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION trf_process_car_audit();
```

```sql
insert into car (name,location) select 'Honda','Paris';
update car set name='Hyundai' where location='Paris';
delete from car;

select * from car_audit;
```

| operation | stamp | userid | id | name | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I | 2023-12-13 11:47:00.364852 | postgres | 1 | Honda | Paris |
| U | 2023-12-13 11:47:00.364852 | postgres | 1 | Hyundai | Paris |
| D | 2023-12-13 11:47:00.364852 | postgres | 1 | Hyundai | Paris |